# java 3D rotation with quaternions

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I have this method for rotating points in 3D using quaternions, but it seems not to work properly:

```
    public static ArrayList<Float> rotation3D(ArrayList<Float> points, double angle, int xi, int yi, int zi)
{
    ArrayList<Float> newPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0;i<points.size();i+=3)
    {
        float x_old = points.get(i);
        float y_old = points.get(i+1);
        float z_old = points.get(i+2);

        double w = Math.cos(angle/2.0);
        double x = xi*Math.sin(angle/2.0);
        double y = yi*Math.sin(angle/2.0);
        double z = zi*Math.sin(angle/2.0);

        float x_new = (float) ((1 - 2*y*y -2*z*z)*x_old + (2*x*y + 2*w*z)*y_old + (2*x*z-2*w*y)*z_old);
        float y_new = (float) ((2*x*y - 2*w*z)*x_old + (1 - 2*x*x - 2*z*z)*y_old + (2*y*z + 2*w*x)*z_old);
        float z_new = (float) ((2*x*z + 2*w*y)*x_old + (2*y*z - 2*w*x)*y_old + (1 - 2*x*x - 2*y*y)*z_old);

        newPoints.add(x_new);
        newPoints.add(y_new);
        newPoints.add(z_new);
    }

    return newPoints;
}
```

If i make this call `rotation3D(list, Math.toRadians(90), 0, 1, 0);` where `points` is `(0,0,10)`, the output is `(-10.0, 0.0, 2.220446E-15)`, but it should be `(-10,0,0)`, right? Could someone take a look at my code and tell me if is there somethig wrong?

Here are 4 screens that represent the initial position of my object, and 3 rotations with -90 degrees (the object is not properly painted, that's a GL issue, that i will work on later):

[image: initial position] 
[image: first rotation]
[image: second rotation]
[image: third rotation]

Comment: Since 2.220446E-15 is such a small number, it seems like it is just a rounding issue within the system.

Comment: Just a comment: The cos and sin are computed on constant values.  Get them out of the loop.

Comment: Indeed, i could optimise the code a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Is the method require so many parameters?

I understand the float[], which represents the original coordinate of the object.

I understand x,y,z , which are the values of quarternion.

But why still need angle? Ans quarternion x,y,z values can create angle, although using complex calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't studied the code but what you get from it is correct: Assuming a left-handed coordinate system, when you rotate the point (0,0,10) 90 degrees around the y-axis (i.e. (0,1,0)) you end up with (-10,0,0).

If your coordinate system is right-handed I think you have to reverse the sign of the angle.

Comment: my bad, i ment (-10,0,0), but the output is (-10.0, 0.0, 2.220446E-15), so not really accurate...

Comment: It's off by only 2*10^-15, a **very** small number. I'd call that pretty accurate.

Comment: I've used this method to rotate the points of a cube in 3D and it's not so accurate as it moves the object on the oZ axis with 10 units.

Comment: Then the result is wrong, the cube ends up in the wrong side of the coordinate axis? The result of the rotation does depend on the handedness of the coordinate system, see edit.

Comment: My system has oY going up, oZ facing the user, and oX perpendicular on oZ so, right-handed. With a negative angle, the cube is translated on the oX axis to the right (on the minus part of axis), but is also rotated. I'll add 2 screens so you can understand easily(and is a parallelepiped, not really a cube).

Comment: I realise that somehow the rotation is made about the system's origin point...and maybe this made me believe it's not accurate...if so, how could i make the parallelipiped rotate about his oY axis and still remain in the wired cube (volume)?

Comment: To rotate an object around a point you have to first translate that point to the origin, then rotate, and then translate back. That is, if R represents the rotation and P the center of rotation, the point x maps to R(x-P)+P.

Comment: Kindly put the whole code to rotate the object around an axis using quaternion. 3d rotation.